# Sveltekit form submission return data

Tags: sveltekit

I have a form in `src/routes/[[lang]]/contact/+page.svelte`

```html
<form method="POST" id="contactForm">
```

All the buttons of the form have `on:click|preventDefault` and the submit button looks like this

```html
<button on:click|preventDefault={sendContact}>
```

The sendContact method:

```js
function sendContact() {
    //Form validation logic
    document.getElementById("contactForm").submit();
}
```

In the `src/routes/[[lang]]/contact/+page.server.js` file I have code that should return the object of `{success: true}`

Code:

```js
export const actions = {
    default: async ({request}) => {
        const formData = await request.formData();
        const email = formData.get('email');
        console.log("test");
        return {success: true};
    }
};
```

I get the log in app console and the formData email.

However when I log out form in the `+page.svelte` file

```js
export let form;
console.log(form);
```

The result is always `null` and it is not updated as numerous instructions say it should be.
[Essentially copied this](https://vercel.com/guides/using-sveltekit-form-actions)

Also checked page variable from $app/stores which did not have my response either.
*Note: also tried including `use:enhance` (without overwriting default) on the form*

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: You should not query the DOM like that; it violates component boundaries. If anything do a relative query (e.g. `event.target.closest('form')`) or use `bind:this` on the form to store a local reference in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as intended with SSR. If that is turned off, you apparently need to use `enhance` (though I think this is a bug).

With `enhance` (would recommend using that anyway), the page will not reload, instead the component state is updated. That means any usage of props in code will have to be reactive to work correctly.

So the log statement would need to be updated to:

```js
$: console.log(form);
```

Otherwise it will only run once on first page load.

More importantly, you cannot just call `submit()` on the form, as that will circumvent `enhance` and thus prevent the component from being updated correctly.

I would recommend not adding handlers on buttons, but rather working with the form's `submit` event. When using `enhance`, the function provided to that should be used instead. You can cancel the submission via the `cancel()` function that is passed to the callback ([docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-use-enhance)).

As a quick fix, you can also keep the button handler but then have to use [`requestSubmit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit) instead.

Comment: I did have ssr turned off. Thank you for the advice, I changed the form handler logic too.